# onChange text is not updating its state

Tags: react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TextInput, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';

import datum from './data';

export default class Signup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { name: 'sff', number: '' };
  }

  signupPressed = () => {
    const { name } = this.state;

    console.log('checkss', name);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
          justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <TextInput
          style={{
            height: 40,
            borderColor: 'gray',
            borderWidth: 1,
            width: '50%',
          }}
          onChangeText={TextInputValue => this.setState({ name })}
          placeholder="Name"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={{
            height: 40,
            borderColor: 'gray',
            borderWidth: 1,
            width: '50%',
          }}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ name })}
          placeholder="Mobile no"
        />
        <Button
          onPress={this.signupPressed}
          title="Signup"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I have Text input but the onChangeText props is not working as it is

**Expected behavior**
Has to log the updated name value from the state when the button is clicked

**Reality**

when I click the button it logs me "checkss" only, not the name value

**What is strange here!!**

when I click the button for the first time it logs me "checkss,sff" but, when I click it for the second time it shows checkss only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in `onChangeText` you'll need to do this,

```
onChangeText={value=>{this.setState({stateVariable:value})}};
```

Comment: Why is this marked as answer? It isn't even valid syntax.

Comment: @George please edit answer with right syntax, or atleast give proper comment whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <TextInput 
        value={this.state.name} 
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1,width:'50%'}}
        onChangeText={(name) => this.setState({name})}
        placeholder="Name" 
    />
```

Try above code it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextInput
  style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1,width:'50%'}}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({name: text })}
  placeholder="Name"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails because you made a mistake when you declare de arrow function

```js
onChangeText={TextInputValue => this.setState({name})}
```

It must be

```js
onChangeText={TextInputValue => this.setState({ name: TextInputValue })}
```

Using Ecma6 can be simplified as

```js
onChangeText={name => this.setState({ name })}
```

To avoid performance issues it is recommended not to use an inline function because is instantiated in all the render cycles. Is better if you create a class method and use it by reference.

```js
export default class Signup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {name:"sff",number:""};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(name) {
    this.setState({ name });
  }
  render() {
    /* rest of code omitted */
    <TextInput
      style={
        { height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1,width:'50%' }
      }
      onChangeText={this.handleChange}
      placeholder="Mobile no"
    />
    /* rest of the code omitted */
  }
}
```